# How convert string in time format in angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime-format

i have a dataset like this in  my controller

```
{
"schedule":[{"day":"Monday","start":"15:00:00"},{"day":"Tuesday","start":"16:30:00"}]
}
```

In my view i would like to use input[time]

```
<div ng-repeat="day in obj.schedule">
 <input  type="time" min="00:00:00" max="23:59:00" placeholder="" ng-model="day.start"/>
</div>
```

It doesn't work because it expects a date, not a string.

How can I convert inside controller my string into time?

I tried with

```
$scope.start = new Date(obj.start)
```

but it doesn't work

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.obj = {
    "schedule": [{
      "day": "Monday",
      "start": "15:00:00"
    }, {
      "day": "Tuesday",
      "start": "16:30:00"
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="day in obj.schedule">
    <input type="time" min="00:00:00" max="23:59:00" placeholder="" ng-model="day.start" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using `ng-model="day.start_time"` shouldn't that be `ng-model="day.start"`

Comment: well, it's a typo while writing post

Comment: Check your question I have added a working snippet and it works

Comment: i don't understand.. inside my project give error:

`Error: ngModel:datefmt
Model is not a date object
Expected `21:00:00` to be a date`

Comment: seems to be a problem with angular 1.3.20 (the one I am using)

Comment: Maybe that could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

If it's expecting a date in your case, maybe try something along these lines

```js
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  var vm = this;
  
  $scope.obj = {
    "schedule": [{
      "day": "Monday",
      "start": "15:00:00"
    }, {
      "day": "Tuesday",
      "start": "16:30:00"
    }]
  }
  
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.obj.schedule.length; i++) {
    $scope.obj.schedule[i].start = stringToDate($scope.obj.schedule[i].start);
  }
 
  function stringToDate(stringDate) {
    var date = new Date();
    var splitDate = stringDate.split(':');
    date.setHours(splitDate[0], splitDate[1], splitDate[2]);
    
    return date.toLocaleTimeString();
  }
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
      <div ng-repeat="day in obj.schedule">
        <input type="time" min="00:00:00" max="23:59:00" placeholder="" ng-model="day.start"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok, the problem is i have `"start": "16:30:00"` and not `"start": stringToDate("16:30:00")`.
This dataset came from external api service, so i can't change it

Comment: Can you iterate through the array of objects? Edited my answer.